# NSFetchedResultController - Custom Sorting on 2 Attributes

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using **NSFetchedResultController** in my Project. Following is a scenario i want to achieve.

- I have a Table Called **Contact** in which i have have 2 attributes **LastMessageDate** and **ContactName**.
- I want to sort Contact objects according to **LastMessageDate**. The objects which don't have **LastMessageDate** should be sorted according to **ContactName** (**Alphabetically**).

For Ex:

Consider i have C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6 as My Contact out of Which C2 and C6 have LastMessageDate Present. So the sorted Contacts should be C2,C6,C1,C3,C4,C5

Comment: What did you try? What did it do?

Comment: Tried Multiple SortDescriptors. But the order of the Contacts was not getting correct due to the condition i have put in (i.e. The objects which don't have LastMessageDate should be sorted according to ContactName (Alphabetically))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use two sort descriptors first will sort all contact in alphabetic order and second will filter according to last message date. see following code -

```
NSSortDescriptor *contactName = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                    initWithKey: @"ContactName" ascending: YES];

NSSortDescriptor *lastMessageDate = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                                    initWithKey: @"LastMessageDate" ascending: YES];


NSArray *sortedArray = [contactArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: contactName, lastMessageDate, nil]];
```

Comment: I have added localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare: method in ContactName Sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set a default date for `LastMessageDate`, to either `distantFuture` or `distantPast`?

Now, when you sort by date these items will be first or last and the second sort descriptor will be used (hence they will be sorted alphabetically).

And your other code would check what the date is and not use when it is equal to `distantFuture` or `distantPast` (which could be in a custom accessor method).